# responseListener not being called for LoginRequest (Android) (Java) (php)

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to make a login with my android app, but I'm very unfamiliar with php and mySQL and need some help.

I've created the register and it successfully uploads my user's data into the database. Though when I try to call LoginRequest, it doesn't tell me whether the login is a success or a fail. I presume that this is because something is wrong with my responseListener or php file.

Here is my Login.php (I have censored my host, user password and database)

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $username, $email, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["email"] = $email;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Here is my LoginRequest class (has all needed imports)

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = ".../Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

This is where I call LoginRequest. I get no runtime exceptions, or compiler exceptions.

```
final Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) { //problem is here, I did some debugging and it turns out this doesn't get called
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success) {
                            System.out.println("success"); 
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("you failed me for the last time");
                        }
                    } catch(JSONException e) {
                        System.out.println("error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), responseListener);
```

Finally this is my table, named user, in my database

```
1   user_idPrimary  int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT   Change 
2   username    varchar(16) utf8_unicode_ci     No  None             Change 
3   email   varchar(30) utf8_unicode_ci     No  None             Change 
4   password    varchar(16) utf8_unicode_ci     No  None             Change
```

I apologize for the lengthy code. Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: i am guessing this line, gets called  System.out.println("you failed me for the last time"); then?

Comment: put a log statement in  onResponse(String response), and log the response.

Comment: also i would deeply you switch to retrofit2. It is a great http  library much better than volley you are using.

Comment: @CaspainCaldion That line does not get called

Comment: what about the log in the onResponse method, try it.

Comment: Nothing in onResponse() gets called

Comment: Ok I will try it @CaspainCaldion thanks

Comment: change  System.out.println("success"); to Log.d("LOG",response.toString()); then filter your log, println is not recommended.

Comment: Use a toast or Log.d(); not System.out.println this android not vanilla java.

Comment: @CaspainCaldion Just tried it, no log comment in "run" showed up

Comment: alright try a toast, if that fails, then no response is received any at all.

Comment: also i do not see where you added responseListener to your requestQueue.

Comment: @CaspainCaldion THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH. it works now. I'm such an idiot. I put that there for the RegisterRequest but not the loginRequest.

Answer (score 0):

```
 LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), responseListener);
```

each request must be added to your request singleton queue. You never added it.

Instantiate the RequestQueue.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

then add the request to the RequestQueue.

```
 queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: alright want any more info before accepting the answer? i strongly recommend switching to retrofit, give it shot bro.

Comment: If I switch to retrofit, will I have to do everything again?

Comment: well not really it uses annotations, for less code, and for faster. start here when you are ready https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client